# TypeError: __init__() отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: 'humidity'

Tags: python, многопоточность

работаю с классами и многопоточностью, но столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу никак обойти.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Project\1234.py", line 38, in <module> create_threads() File "D:\Project\1234.py", line 28, in create_threads my_thread1 MyThread(temperature) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'humidity'`

Задание выглядит следующим образом: нужно формировать значения температуры и влажности, а затем выводить каждое из них по 3 раза по порядку с интервалом от 1 до 5 секунд.

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__ (self, temperature, humidity):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.humidity = humidity
    
    def run(self):
        amount = random.randint(1, 5)
        time.sleep(amount)
                
        self.temperature = random.uniform(0, 40)
        b = float('{:.1f}'.format(self.temperature))
        msg_temp = "Температура %s °С." % b
        print(msg_temp)

        self.humidity = random.randint(0, 100)
        msg_hum = "Влажность %s процента." % self.humidity
        print(msg_hum) 
            
def create_threads():
    for i in range(3):
        temperature = (i+1)
        my_thread1 = MyThread(temperature)
        my_thread1.start()
        my_thread1.join()
    for n in range(3):
        humidity = (n+1)
        my_thread2 = MyThread(humidity)
        my_thread2.start()
        my_thread2.join()    
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Comment: Так вы не передали обязательный аргумент humidity при создании экземпляра класса.  Разве не?

Answer (score 0):

Типы аргументов функции

При вызове функции аргументы можно передавать двумя способами:

как `позиционные` - передаются в том же порядке, в котором они определены при создании функции. То есть, порядок передачи аргументов определяет, какое значение получит каждый аргумент

как `ключевые` - передаются с указанием имени аргумента и его значения. В таком случае, аргументы могут быть указаны в любом порядке, так как их имя указывается явно.

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__ (self, temperature=None, humidity=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.humidity = humidity
    
    def run(self):
        amount = random.randint(1, 5)
        time.sleep(amount)
        if self.temperature:        
            self.temperature = random.uniform(0, 40)
            b = float('{:.1f}'.format(self.temperature))
            msg_temp = "Температура %s °С." % b
            print(msg_temp)

        if self.humidity:
            self.humidity = random.randint(0, 100)
            msg_hum = "Влажность %s процента." % self.humidity
            print(msg_hum) 
            
def create_threads():
    for i in range(3):
        temperature = (i+1)
        my_thread1 = MyThread(temperature=temperature)
        my_thread1.start()
        my_thread1.join()
    for n in range(3):
        humidity = (n+1)
        my_thread2 = MyThread(humidity=humidity)
        my_thread2.start()
        my_thread2.join()    
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```